# VHDL component multiplexer don't return value in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus, mux

I am trying to make an ALU with an adder, mux2 and mux4 component with port map. 
I have write the ALU it pass compiling OK. The problem is when I try in modelsim to give values, the adder works ok, but the mux2 (sub_module) & mux4 (sub_module x2) don't give output. I replace 2-3 times the mux code and the problem is the same. I only get UUUUUUUU values for outY.
I have minimized the code.

[ModelSim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TdC.png)

Main ALU minimized

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ALU7_minimal is
    Port ( inpA : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) :="10110001";
             inpB : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) :="00011001";
        ALUS0 : in  STD_LOGIC := '0';
            outY : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end ALU7_minimal;

architecture Behavioral  of ALU7_minimal is

component sub_module
port(x,y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
s: in STD_LOGIC;
z: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;


begin

U0: sub_module port map (inpA, inpB, ALUS0, outY );


end Behavioral ;
```

mux2-1

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity sub_module is
port(x,y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
s: in STD_LOGIC;
z: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end sub_module ;

architecture Behavioral of sub_module is

begin

process (x,y,s) is
begin
if (s ='0') then
z <= x;
else
z <= y;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. [The problem can't be replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBbt5.jpg) from the information provided using inputs gleaned from the linked waveform. Note U3 (adder8bit) is unbound (and isn't responsible for all the 'U's),`out0` is driven but not used as an input, nor is `out12`.

Comment: I have minimized the example.

Comment: Now if you'd only provided a reproducible example. [The problem still can't be replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQrKI.jpg) from the information using inputs gleaned from the linked waveform. Consider providing (and using) a testbench. You appear to be doing something procedurally wrong.

Comment: Thanks again. That is exactly the problem. The code is simple but still producing error. Maybe the problem isn't in the code and there is a setting in Modelsim that need to look at? Do you know any other test environment that I can try the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference for others that experience the same problem (My teacher discover it):
You needed to import into the modelsim all components files before you run the simulation. Paradox the adder of 1bit and 8bit was working even if I haven't import them, but the mux(2-1 /4-1) won't given any result. When I imported all the component files (and not just the main program), the ModelSim show the results correctly. 
Thank for your time and help guys, really appreciate.

Comment: And again the problem can't be replicated from the question. How does that aid future readers?

Answer (score 0):

no need for a process!

```
begin
with s select
    z <= x  when '0',
         y  when '1',
        'U' when others;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: A concurrent assignment statement is elaborated into a process with an equivalent sequential assignment statement.